# Return all links to photos in a flickr set

Tags: json, photo, flickr

I want to use all the photos in a Flickr set and in order to do so (and not infringe upon copyright etc) have to link back to the owner.  I can't seems to find anything in the Flickr API to return the html code for each individual photo.

At present I'm faced with copying and pasting all the html code from the "share" button.  Not a pleasant prospect.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You want to link back to the image in Flickr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want a link back to the images or photosets?

See here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

There are examples for linking to images directly, individual photos, photosets, etc.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.   That gives me the links I need but when I try to embed them I get the response "this photo is currently unavailable".  I think I may need to add an API key for it.

Comment: It sounds like you would.  Give it a try and let us know!

Comment: Trigger finger... I'd forgotten the file extension!  Thanks so much Brandon.  Helped out a great deal.

Comment: And yes, the photographer is getting full credit... I've emailed him for permission already and I'll link back directly to his set.